# Mesh simplification algorithm implemented in javascript

Tags: javascript, import, three.js, simplification

I searched for some easily portable mesh simplification implementations to port them to javascript, e.g. to use them directly when importing a model. I found some possible candidates:

- http://truesculpt.googlecode.com/hg-history/2936b0558a85ec55d2235847e1b36a6875253fb5/Doc/mesh_simplification.pdf

  - http://www.cg.tuwien.ac.at/studentwork/VisFoSe98/msh/
  - http://sajty.elementfx.com/progressivemesh/GSoC2012.pdf
  - http://gts.sourceforge.net/

My question is, why is there no javascript implementation existent especially for a library like three.js where level of detail is a well supported feature? Will it take ages to do the computations in js? I dont think so.. And crosscompiling one of the c++ implementations should also not be so hard right?

Comment: more algorithms than you ever imagined: http://lodbook.com/source/ (not in javascript :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no it does not take forever,

http://jabtunes.com/labs/3d/bunny/

This is the answer to your question, edit the SimplifyModfier.js to suit your needs. I did that and it took around 80 seconds for simplifying a mesh with 25K triangles to 1K triangles. Let me know in case you need further assistance   :-)

Comment: That looks great, do you know if it works with textured models as well?

Comment: Thanks :-)

Yes here is an implementation which works with texture and UV coordinates.

http://www.tres-graficos.jp/blog/files/article.php?id=56

Comment: Unfortunately the jabtunes.com link is broken.